# LightningAlert.open from New and Changed Aura Components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, lightning-components, alert, summer-22

hope everyone is doing fine.

I`m new to Salesforce and still learning a lot from it. I need to chance some of the alert() function to the new LightningAlert, due to Chrome and Safari retiring support for the alert() functino.

I'm having trouble to execute (sandbox) the aura example of new LightningAlert that is going live with Summer 22. I don`t know what could I be doing wrong, can someone help, please?

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_aura_components.htm&type=5&release=238

CMP: NewAlert.cmp

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader" access="global" >

    <aura:import library="lightning:alert" property="LightningAlert" />
    <lightning:button label="Open Alert" onclick="{!c.openAlert }"/>
</aura:component>
```

CONTROLLER: NewAlertController.js

```
({
    openAlert: function(cmp, event) {
        this.LightningAlert.open({
            message: 'this is the alert message',
            theme: 'error',
            label: 'Error!',
        }).then(function() {
            console.log('alert is closed');
        });
    }
});
```

I`m getting this error when I push the button on Record Page:

Uncaught Action failed: c:NewAlert$controller$openAlert [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'LightningAlert')]

Comment: Just checking if the api version of your component 55?

Comment: Yeah, it is version 55

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is a Summer 22 bug with `LightningAlert` (aura version) when relevant methods are called directly from `controller.js`.

Reported error is reproduced even with component having API version >= 54.0

> Uncaught Action failed: c:cmpName$controller$openAlert [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'LightningAlert')]

**To eliminate the error, possible workaround is to call the method from helper.js:**

*component.cmp*

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,force:appHostable" access="global" >
    <aura:import library="lightning:alert" property="LightningAlert" />
    <aura:import library="lightning:prompt" property="LightningPrompt" />
    <lightning:button onclick="{! c.openAlert }" label="Aura Open Alert"/>
    <lightning:button onclick="{! c.openPrompt }" label="Aura Open Prompt"/>

</aura:component>
```

*controller.js*

```
({
    openAlert: function(cmp, event, helper) {
        helper.openAlert(cmp, event);
    },
    openPrompt: function(cmp, event, helper) {
        helper.openPrompt(cmp, event);
    }
});
```

*helper.js*

```
({
    openAlert: function(cmp, event) {
        this.LightningAlert.open({
            message: "this is the alert message",
            theme: "error",
            label: "Error!"
        }).then(function() {
            console.log("alert is closed");
        })
    },
    openPrompt: function(cmp, event) {
        this.LightningPrompt.open({
            message: 'this is the prompt message',
            variant: 'headerless',
            label: 'Please Respond',
            defaultValue: 'default input value',
        }).then(function(result) {
            // result is input value if clicked "OK"
            // result is null if clicked "Cancel"
            console.log('prompt result is', result);
        });
    }
})
```

**Note**: no issue observed when using the new alert methods in LWC components

Comment: That worked .Seems like we only can use this new lightningAlert lib in Aura components with this workaround. Thank very much @Shamina.